# Generalize For and Malloc's size C

Tags: c, file, for-loop, struct, malloc

I have a file with 20 million records and I allocated space with  `malloc`  to be able to contain it.
The problem is that I would like to do it more general, without putting 20 million in `for` statement and declaration of `malloc`.
Is there a way to generalize the code for any file size? if I pass him a bigger file, he should still be able to read it. How can I do this?

**main.c**

```
struct Fields{
    int i;
    char f1[20];
    int f2;
    float f3;
};

int main() {
struct Fields* files;
    files = malloc(sizeof(struct Fields)*20000000);
                                                      //I have to generalize this 20000000
for (n=0; n<sizeof(struct Fields)*20000000; n++) { 

     //code 

}
}
```

Comment: So you want to know how to determine the size of a file?

Comment: Yes @ScottHunter

Comment: Remember that when you loop over an array, fixed-size or dynamically allocated with `malloc`, you loop over *elements*. This makes the `sizeof(struct Fields)` multiplication in the loop condition seem very wrong.

Comment: You could use a variable of type *size_t* instead of that 20000000... but... I would instead consider *memory mapped I/O for such large files*

Comment: @AnttiHaapala good advice, but OP has just started learning C. I do not think it is for him right now

Comment: Yep :) @P__JsupportswomeninPoland

Comment: I would like to understand how to determine the size of the file, before allocating the memory, I can't write the number 20 million directly. @AnttiHaapala

Comment: The problem isn't to determine the file size, it's rather trivial actually. No the problem is to determinate the number of *records* (elements) in the file. And this depends on the file type and its *exact* contents. Can you tell us how the file was created? How it was written to? Is it a text file? A binary file? Does it contain any more data than the data you want to read? Was the file created on a system similar to the one it's supposed to be read from (i.e. are both x86 PC-like systems)? Is the same compiler used for both writer and reader programs?

Comment: The file is a .csv with 20.000.000 records, 4 fields each one. I have to write all records in an array and after this I have to sort them in three different way @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Then to find out the size, simply count the number of lines. Pay close attention to the corner-case when the last line might not end in a newline.

Comment: How can I count the lines? I tried `for (n=0; n<sizeof(files)/sizeof(files[0]); n++)` but it doesn't work. It should be the number of lines . @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Two problems with that: First of all it's not the actual contents of the file, you need to actually *read* the file to determine the number of lines in it. Secondly, that division only works for actual arrays, not for pointers since the `sizeof` a pointer is the size of the pointer itself and not what it points to.

Comment: You could combine the counting and the reading of the data into a single loop: Start by assuming the file contains `X` records, and allocate memory for that. Then read the records in an unbound loop. If you start to read records beyond the currently allocated limit, then *reallocate* the memory and increase the size by a suitable amount. Continue to do that until all the data have been read from the file. Since you also need an index for the current element to read into, after the loop the index should be equal to the number of records in the file, and can be used in future loops.

Comment: Ok, but what is the condition that I have to write to tell "him" the file ends and there aren't more lines? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: When e.g. `fgets` return a `NULL` pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read a line-based text file (which CSV files are) you could do something like the following *pseudo* code:

```
// Capacity of the allocated array, number of elements actually allocated
size_t current_capacity = 100000;

// Number of elements to increase capacity by if needed
size_t const capacity_increment = 100000;

// Current size of the array, the number of initialized elements in the array
size_t size = 0;

// Initial allocation
struct Fields *records = malloc(current_capacity * sizeof *records);

while (read_line_from_file(file_pointer, line_buffer))
{
    // Is the current array full?
    if (size >= current_capacity)
    {
        // Increase the capacity of the array
        current_capacity += capacity_increment;

        // And reallocate the array
        struct Field *temp_records = realloc(records, current_capacity * sizeof *records);
        if (temp_records == NULL)
        {
            // TODO: Handle error!
            edit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        records = temp_records;
    }

    records[size++] = parse_cvs_line(line_buffer);
}

// Unless there was an error reading the file, all records have been read
// from the file.
// The number or records read into the array is in the size variable.

// Just for debugging:
printf("The number of records in the file was %zu\n", size);

// You can now use the size variable for further loops,
// as in for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) { ... }
```

Worst-case scenario this will waste memory for `99999` records. But if the real file have at least 20 million records as stated in the question, this will be less then 5%. You can fine-tune this to find a good mix of performance vs. possible space waste.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you handle a binary file or a text file but in both cases you should divide the read. I give an example for a binary file that I read packet of bytes by packet of bytes. You could do the same line by line for a text file. In both cases you can reuse a same buffer for each packet you read and you must do the read within the loop :

```
buffer          = malloc(sizeof(struct Fields)* CAPACITY); // Choose a capacity
size_t fileSize = fsize(filename);
size_t location = 0;
int file        = open(filename, O_RDONLY);

while (location < fileSize) 
{ 
     size_t remaining = fileSize - location;
     int result = read(file, buffer, remaining < capacity ? remaining : capacity);
     if (result == -1) {
         printf("Error while reading the file : %s\n", filename);
         break; 
     }
     
     // Do something with the packet

     location += capacity; 
}
close(file);
free(buffer);
```